# listView.setOnItemLongClickListener does not work in Android studio

Tags: android

I want to open the popup window when i select long press on Listview Item .First 4 to 5 days it works but right now it does not open popup window or does not print any Log message on log cat while press the  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener.How to resolve this issue.Thanks in advanced

Here is my code

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
            {
                 Log.e("$$$$ ", "selectedAllPost_ItemActivityId = " + 
                 selectedAllPost_ItemActivityId + " listitem_pos = " + listitem_pos)                        
                 initiateModifyPopUp();
                 return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: is it the log getting printed ?

Comment: No does not anythind print of log message on log cat.

Comment: can you show your adaptor class, where you have put onclick listener for textview and imageview

Comment: Lots of code in Adapter class. Is that ok ?

Comment: yes ok , you can show the code

Comment: Sorry i cant post it because ,  it can post only 30000 chars at time and in my adapter above 44000 chars .So how can i post ArrayAdapter class

Comment: first comment all those lines where you have put onclicklistener in Adapter class. After that run the project and try longclick listener in listview. is it working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96120/discussion-between-p-ld-and-vivek-patel).

Answer (score 0):

to detect long click you have to set it as long click-able. you can set it either in xml or in code..

**xml**

```
<ListView
.....
android:longClickable="true"/>
```

or dynamically `listView.setLongClickable(true);`

Comment: Still not working . Actually the listview item with lots of textview and images.

Comment: do you have separate listener for all those views ?

Comment: yes . But the separate listener for all those views using in AdpaterClass

Answer (score 0):

Please set return `true` for `onLongClick(View v)`